# Possible to disable custom Javascript keybindings in Safari?

Tags: safari, keyboard, javascript

I have a couple of decades experience using Emacs, so the Emacs-like keybindings for text editing on Mac OS X are very nice.  Unfortunately, some websites (ahem) choose to override these with Javascript.  For example, one of them makes <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> insert the text `**strong text**`, rather than going back one character.

Is there any way to make Safari ignore Javascript keybindings that try to remap the standard OS X keybindings?

Comment: I don't know any general way to do that, but you could use GreaseKit to disable the WMD shortcuts. See [Is there a way to disable the hotkeys? - Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys?lq=1).

Comment: Thanks for the link!  It's frustrating to see that they think it's fine just because people didn't complain enough.  (I've been using SE sites for years and I didn't realize I needed to start complaining on day 1 for my voice to be heard.)  I'm hesitant to add any web browser extensions, though, since the first part of any web browser issue diagnosis is "disable all extensions".

Comment: I'm with Ken. I personally can't count how many times I've had to use "undo" because my hands forgot I was on an SE site :S

Comment: I was going to suggest that you could disable javascript... It fixed your problem, but it created a new one — I could no longer post comments on StackExchange... =P

Comment: Is this question about the site here? or about disabling javascript everywhere? I could move it to our meta as a bug report, but there's already several requests for this site wide. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/option-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-wmd

Comment: It's been a while since I've used it, but the Privoxy proxy server (http://www.privoxy.org/) has the feature to modify javascript to change behavior. If you're willing to run a proxy server, that is an option. Perhaps there's a more modern implementation in the form of a browser plugin that provides a similar feature?

Comment: @timb I'd say go ahead and answer. +50 up for grabs and worst case, a better answer comes along (instead of an edit to help your beginning of an answer.) We're going on almost a year without a single answer, so even a partial one would help.

Answer (score 7):

Here is [Rob W's script from meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys), updated to only block cntrl-* and fixed so that it works with NinjaKit which is a safari extension for running user scripts.

NinjaKit:
https://github.com/os0x/NinjaKit

Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Cya WMD shortcuts
// @namespace      Rob W
// @version        1.0
// @include          http://apple.stackexchange.com/*
// @include          http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include          http://superuser.com/*
// @include          http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @include          http://serverfault.com/*
// @include          http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @include          http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include          http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @include          http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include          http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include          http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include          http://stackapps.com/*
// @run-at         document-end
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
    var p = document.getElementById('wmd-input');
    console.log("wmd-input:" + p);
    if (p) {
        p = p.parentNode;

        function ignore(e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
        p.addEventListener('keydown', ignore, true);
        p.addEventListener('keypress', ignore, true);
        p.addEventListener('keyup', ignore, true);
    }
})();
```

Comment: [More info...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys)

Comment: [This script as a chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-stackexchange-editor-k/nhdklhaffdlobbdgheaehofbnfebeddm?hl=en-US)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've used it, but the [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) proxy server has the feature to modify javascript to change behavior. If you're willing to run a proxy server, that is an option.

I did look (though not exhaustively), and didn't see a browser plugin that rewrote content (xml, html, CSS, or javascript) like privoxy does. In Privoxy's web page, look for the js-annoyances filter. That is where you'll find examples of rewriting javascript.

Perhaps there's a more modern implementation in the form of a browser plugin that provides a similar feature, but privoxy used to work fine for this use case.